# how to stop lightning experience forced transition (2019)

Tags: lightning-experience

My company received an e-mail from Salesforce telling us we'll be transitioning to Lightning in 54 days.

This is pretty catastrophic for us as Lightning Experience is very slow, the interface is unfamiliar and painful to use for our users (and myself.)  We simply can't use it because of the terrible performance/  unresponsive and alien interface.

I tried searching how to disable Lightning Experience and came across the following article: https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=lex_enable_turn_off.htm&type=5

I followed these steps and this switches you back to Classic and removes the "Try Lightning Experience" link at the top right. Apparently one of our execs needs access to that button to switch to Lightning Experience for some custom dashboard he uses, so switching this off this way is not an option. I have to leave it on and stay in Classic.

I'm worried that our org will be forcefully transitioned to Lightning Experience in a couple months without the ability to switch back to Classic. How can I prevent this?

Comment: contact your salesforce rep.

Answer (score 1):

If you are not assigning any standard profile except system admin to any of the users in your Org, You can easily handle the critical update.

If you are having users assigned with Standard profiles, You can clone it and use the custom cloned profile.

What I would suggest is disable below system permission on the custom profile level:-

[image]

And then, create two permission set where you will define:-

> 1. The ability to switch to Lightning Experience and hide the switch back to Classic option
> 2. The ability to switch to Lightning Experience and show the switch back to classic option
> 3. The users do not see the switch to Lightning Experience option

You will be able to manage this based on the system permission highlighted in the image above.

Once done, Identify your users and assign the appropriate permission set and it will solve your problem.

You can read this fact sheet to know more about it:- [Turn On Lightning Experience critical update FAQ](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=000273853&language=en_US&type=1)